# What is the PRNG algorithm used in Rust's `rand` crate?

Tags: random, rust

I'm writing a web app that will do some financial model simulations. Just for fun and an opportunity to learn new things, I have decided to offload all the math and simulations to a WebAssembly and implement that wasm in Rust.

I am therefore looking at PRNGs for Rust. I found a [Mersenne Twister crate](https://docs.rs/mersenne_twister/latest/mersenne_twister/) and MT is obviously a well-established algorithm (even used by default in several languages), but this particular crate does not seem to be very popular. I also understand that Rust has a [`rand`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/) crate "built-in" (if that's even a thing) but I haven't found any info as to:

- What is the algorithm used in `rand`?
- How does that algorithm stack up to others (e.g. MT) in terms of randomness quality?

To be clear: I'm evaluating algorithms for **statistical randomness** (simulating stochastic processes), **not** cryptographic security.

Comment: The `rand` crate is open-source and very well documented. There's a page on the included generators: https://rust-random.github.io/book/guide-rngs.html

Comment: If you start on the page you linked to and follow appropriate links, you'll get to [Struct rand::rngs::StdRng](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html) "The current algorithm used is the ChaCha block cipher with 12 rounds." I suggest that you confirm I went down the correct path.

Comment: Re: algorithms, avoid MT. It's bloated and doesn't produce very good randomness. For simulation you almost certainly want something in the xoshiro family, like `xoshiro256++`.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm used as the default PRNG is ChaCha with 12 rounds.  This is used in `ThreadRng` and `StdRng`, both of which are typically seeded from the system's CSPRNG.

ChaCha12, like with all cryptographically secure PRNGs, passes the *next bit test*.  That is, given an arbitrary amount of output from the PRNG, the probability of correctly guessing the next bit is negligibly better than even.  This is the best standard that any PRNG can offer, and it is substantially better than the Mersenne Twister, which does not pass this test.

ChaCha is typically very fast, and for most purposes ChaCha12 is a good option.  If you need more robust cryptographic security, ChaCha20 (that is, ChaCha with 20 rounds) is the most conservative.  The best known attacks on ChaCha are on seven rounds.

If you just need a fast, non-cryptographic PRNG, ChaCha8 is a good option.  It is typically faster than almost all other PRNGs, including, in my testing, PCG and Xoshiro256++ (which is the current `SmallRng`), and is still considered cryptographically secure (and therefore passes the next bit test), but due to the low security margin, it would not be a responsible choice for cryptographic use.  It is, however, a great choice for most other uses due to its speed and statistical properties.

Comment: Wow, that's really fast. Can you share the code showing that ChaCha8 is faster than xoshiro256++?

Comment: I don't have it up anywhere, but it's just wiring up various Rust crates, including the `rand_chacha` crate, and piping several gigabytes of data from one or the other.

Comment: I tried this super basic thing with the rand_cacha crate, but ChaCha8 is about 5 times slower than xoshiro256++. Can you have a look? Maybe I made an obvious mistake.
https://gist.github.com/vigna/65dbf7690083a6eed405f8fcd36d25a4

Comment: More precisely: ChaCha8 is 5 times slower than xoshiro256++ on ARM, but just 2 times slower on 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700KF.

Comment: Generating a single `u64` isn't helpful because ChaCha8 has more overhead for small numbers of values.  Generate a large amount of data, like a couple megabytes at a time.

Comment: I think you made some serious mistakes in your tests. This gist generates a billion u64 using a single call to fill(). The relative speed of the generators is exactly the same as the other test. https://gist.github.com/vigna/e8b2bf6b09c194d5c6c414647a140782

Comment: I'm certain I didn't because I have the proof on my machine, but I don't think this comment space is the appropriate place to have this discussion since it's too small for me to post a reasonable amount of code.

Comment: It's OK, at this point smart readers can easily understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

> I also understand that Rust has a rand crate "built-in" (if that's even a thing) but I haven't found any info as to:

> - What is the algorithm used in rand?

The documentation requires jumping around but seems pretty clear?

[`random`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/fn.random.html) redirects to [`thread_rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/fn.thread_rng.html), which directs to the [`ThreadRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html) structure, which documents that it uses the same PRNG as [`StdRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html) which says:

> The current algorithm used is the ChaCha block cipher with 12 rounds. Please see [this relevant rand issue](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/issues/932) for the discussion.

> *How does that algorithm stack up to others (e.g. MT) in terms of randomness quality?

ChaCha is a cryptographically secure PRNG (it's what's used for every BSD's system RNG as well as Linux), whereas MT most definitely is not; and ChaCha is vastly superior to MT in terms of randomness quality.

That does have a cost though, CSPRNG tend to be slower than non-secure PRNGs (as they have different goals entirely). Though MT is not exactly fast as far as PRNG goes, so chacha12 may well be competitive.

`rand` also provides [`SmallRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/struct.SmallRng.html), a *non-cryptographic* PRNG with rather good statistical properties which is *extremely* fast.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just want to comment that for me (and I'm only just starting to learn Rust, not even entirely understanding concepts like traits etc.) it was not at all obvious which links to follow, and I think other beginners might struggle as well. In fact, I was led to a subpage of docs.rs/rand by Google and subsequently completely missed the off-site link to rust-random.github.io which contains the real wealth of information. (Thanks to @denys-seguret for mentioning that in a comment.)

Comment: Note that all the lins I posted (aside from the github issue) are on docs.rs/rand

Comment: Also I think the information on rust-random.github.io is not up to date: since `StdRng` is now ChaCha12 its performances should be between ChaCha8 and ChaCha20 (and probably closer to the former than the latter).

Comment: There is also the [`rand::rngs`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/index.html) page (linked to both from the crate main page, and shows up in search results) that states, *"`StdRng` is a CSPRNG chosen for good performance and trust of security (based on reviews, maturity and usage). The current algorithm is ChaCha12, which is well established and rigorously analysed. `StdRng` provides the algorithm used by `ThreadRng` but without periodic reseeding."*